# Passing parameters from Group Policy to VBScript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, gpo

So i need to push a batch script out as a login script through Group Policy

Batch Script Example:

```
@echo off
Set USPS=%1 %2
Command %USPS%
```

I'm using a VB Script to call the .bat file

VB Script

```
Dim var1, var2
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Parameter1, begin with index0
var1 = WScript.Arguments(0)

'Parameter2
var2 = WScript.Arguments(1)

objShell.Run "Script.bat" var1 & var2, 0, True
```

I'm placing parameters in the script parameters text box in group policy
[image: GPO Screenshot]

So what im trying to do is pass the two parameters (Username and Password)to the VB Script then have the VB Script pass them to the batch file but it isn't passing them any like to point out where im messing up?

I'm doing it this way because i need to hide the username and password so i cant put them inside the scripts.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using VB script to call a batch file?  Why not call the batch file directly?  Or if you want to use VB script, why not use it for the whole thing and leave out the batch script?

Comment: Because it causes issues on execution when i call it directly plus i need to hide the prompt box from the user that's why im using `, 0, True` at the end of the vbs

Comment: So do everything with VBS and forget about the batch script.

Comment: i don't have a great knowledge of VBS, say the command above is `"\\server\Folder\program.exe" /remoteauth %USPS%` can the switches from the .exe program be used in vbs?

Comment: Of course they can -- you already seem to have figured that out on your own because that's basically what you did in this line:  `objShell.Run("Script.bat Var1 Var2"), 0, True`

Comment: ok i try converting it to VBS Thanks

Comment: Still, it sounds like you need to read a couple arguments in your script. `WScript.Arguments(0)` is going to be the 1st (username). `WScript.Arguments(1)` will be the 2nd (password).

Comment: @Bond Yea i've been trying that as well i keep getting expected ')' (VBS Edited above)

Comment: Get rid of the parens in your `objShell.Run` statement. You're also not concatenating properly. You need a space after your BAT file and a space between args. `objShell.Run "Script.bat " & var1 & " " & var2, 0, True`

Comment: Check my comment above. I edited it to show you how it should look.

Comment: @Bond brilliant ! that worked thanks a bunch if you want to put he answer below do so and ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can grab the args to your script and pass them along:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "This script needs two args."
    WScript.Quit -1
End If

Dim var1, var2
var1 = WScript.Arguments(0)
var2 = WScript.Arguments(1)

With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "Script.bat " & var1 & " " & var2, 0, True

   ' Or, if you want to leave the batch file out of this...
    .Run Chr(34) & "\\server\Folder\program.exe" & Chr(34) & " /remoteauth " & var1 & " " & var2
End With
```