# No parameter in GPO logon script passed?

Tags: windows, authentication, vbscript, winlogon

Is it possible to run secedit in logon script ?
I wrote a script to add some COM and DCOM settings. To run it by doubble click or via cmd.exe works fine.
 
But it is not working as a logon script.
MsgBox is also not working at logon ......
Is it because secedit is not working at the start or because I run it via my domain controller ?
EDIT:
secedit isn´t the problem. I added some MsgBoxes to control the script at a logon and it is starting.
But the parameter I added to the GPO in the domain controler are not there.
 I made this :

`On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox WScript.Arguments(0)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox WScript.Arguments(1)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
    End If`

And the output is "out of range" twice.
So why am I not able to set these two parameters in the GPO like [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770908.aspx)?

Comment: Please include your script so it can be reviewed for errors

Comment: Although I'd find it odd if Microsoft really did it that way with their once beloved scripting language, I noticed that all exemaple parameters in that technet article are parameters for wscript.exe not for the script itself. Maybe it is reserved for those parameters and you should pass yours directly in the script name? (Although I could not find evidence for this thesis in a quick search imo it should just work the way you described you did it, also worked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006179/passing-parameters-from-group-policy-to-vbscript e.g.)

Comment: @Syberdoor I tried to pass the parameters behind the scriptname, but it doesnt work ( I asked myself why it should... there is a extra box for paramters)